# Scan a column in one df using column in another df and if condition is met assign the create an extra column in the second df and assign value

Tags: r, dataframe

I got data like this

```
    structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), code2 = c("24600", 
"2400", "718", "19C11", "2021", "41C200", "G8511", "2021")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I want to use the "code" column in the above df2 and scan it through the following df1, and if the code is matching then assign the value from the "score" column in df1

```
        structure(list(code = c("718", "E0012", "G8511", "209BF", "466D", 
    "2021"), score = c(1, 1, 3, 6, 1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

and I want the final df to look like this

```
        structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), code2 = c("24600", 
    "2400", "718", "19C11", "2021", "41C200", "G8511", "2021"), score2 = c(NA, 
    NA, 1, NA, 2, NA, 3, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: You can try `merge(df1, df2, by.x = "code2", by.y = "code", all.x = T)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), code2 = c("24600", 
                                                         "2400", "718", "19C11", "2021", "41C200", "G8511", "2021")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

df2 <- structure(list(code = c("718", "E0012", "G8511", "209BF", "466D", 
                        "2021"), score = c(1, 1, 3, 6, 1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))


res <- df1 %>% mutate(score2 = ifelse(code2 %in% df2$code, df2$score, NA))
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the ID column in the first df. In the first df I only got the code and score and In the second df for each id , when their code column matches the code in the df1, create a score2 column and assign the value in the df1 score column.

Comment: I tried this `df2$score <- with(df2, ifelse(code2 %in% df$code, df$score, NA))` but it gives the wring results.

Comment: I mean I don't have the id column in the second df. Id column only present in one. Therefore, the code columns have to be matched and the value from the score column, need to inserted in a new score column in the first df.